# Why std::distance doesnt work on mix of const and nonconst iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Like the question says, I'm wondering about the reason for that. Because I get an error when I try to get the distance between `const` and non-`const` iterators.

```
vector<int> v;
auto it=v.begin();
auto cit=v.cbegin();
distance(it,cit);


no matching function for call to ‘distance(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >&)
```

From my limited understanding of iterators, I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a mutable iterator and a constant iterator in the call to `std::distance`, so template argument deduction is failing. You can fix this by specifying the template argument explicitly.

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto i1 = v.begin();
auto i2 = v.cbegin();

auto dist = std::distance<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>( i1, i2 );
```

Answer (score 7):

That's because [std::distance()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) only takes one template parameter:

```
template <class InputIterator>
iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
distance(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Therefore, `first` and `last` must be convertible to the same type, and template resolution will unfortunately not consider that `vector<int>::iterator` is convertible to `vector<int>::const_iterator`.

Comment: hmm why dont they just create template with 2 template params? Is it possible to do it in cpp core lang? What Im asking is that a design decision or a lang limitation?

Comment: to be clear, i know they can make template with 2 template params, but Im wondering would it conflict with 1 template param version

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, I would say design decision. It's simpler that way, and computing the distance between iterators of different kinds (say, a random access iterator and a forward iterator) is probably not something you want to do very often. You could indeed write a version with two template arguments, but what real-world problem would that solve?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: It wouldn't conflict, and there's no reason why you couldn't define your own two-parameter version (although not in `std` obviously). It's just one of many little details of the standard that aren't quite as good as they could be; maybe the next version will fix it.

Comment: "`first` and `last` must have the same type," *or be convertible to the same type*. Conveniently, the standard requires that `vector::iterator` be convertible to `vector::const_iterator`.

Comment: @Rob, true, I was being too simplistic. Answer updated accordingly, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

As everyone says, it's because `std::distance` only takes one iterator type, and template argument deduction is not able to choose which one it should be (even though only one of them is possible given that `iterator` converts to `const_iterator` but not back).

It might be worth writing a template something like this:

```
template <typename Container>
typename Container::const_iterator constify(const Container &, typename Container::iterator it) {
    return it;
}
```

Then you can force the template deduction like this:

```
std::distance(constify(v, it), cit);
```

instead of writing out that great long type. The `Container&` parameter is a shame, it's there because AFAIK `Container` can't be deduced from an iterator argument alone.

Answer (score 3):

`std::distance` will work with those two iterators what is not working is the template argument inference. The compiler is trying to resolve what type to substitute for the first template argument and has two potential candidates, which as per the standard ends up in a failure.

You can do one of two things, either compare only iterators of the same type, or provide the type to the template:

```
std::distance<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>( v.begin(), v.cbegin() );
```