# auto it = vector.begin() resulting type is not convertible to const_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, implicit-conversion

Containers are required to provide an `iterator` type which is implicitly convertible to a `const_iterator`.  Given this, I am trying to use `auto` to initialize an object via `vector::begin()`, and use that resulting object in `std::distance` where the RHS is a `const_iterator`.  This isn't working.  Here is a complete example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector <char> Packet;
typedef std::vector <Packet> Packets;

template <typename Iter> 
Iter next_upto (Iter begin, Iter end, size_t n)
{
    Iter ret = begin;
      for (; n > 0 && ret != end; ++ret, --n)
            ;   
        return ret;
}

Packets::const_iterator Process (Packets::const_iterator begin, Packets::const_iterator end)
{
  Packets::const_iterator ret = begin;
  while (ret != end)
    ++ret;  // do something
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  Packets test (100); // vector of 100 default-initialized packets

  // process them 10 at a time
  for (auto it = test.begin();
    it != test.end();
    it = next_upto (it, test.end(), 10))
  {
     auto itr = Process (it, next_upto (it, test.end(), 10));
     Packets::const_iterator it2 = it; 
     const size_t n1 = std::distance (it2, itr);
     const size_t n = std::distance (it, itr);
     std::cout << "Processed " << n << " packets\n";
  }
}
```

Under g++ 4.8.1 (and 4.8.2) compiling this yields:

```
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hacks.dir/main.o
FAILED: /usr/bin/g++    -Wall -std=c++11 -g -MMD -MT CMakeFiles/hacks.dir/main.o -MF "CMakeFiles/hacks.dir/main.o.d" -o CMakeFiles/hacks.dir/main.o -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:39:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘distance(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<char>*, std::vector<std::vector<char> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<char>*, std::vector<std::vector<char> > >&)’
      const size_t n = std::distance (it, itr);
                                             ^
main.cpp:39:45: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:66:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:60,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114:5: note: template<class _InputIterator> typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::distance(_InputIterator, _InputIterator)
     distance(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:39:45: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_InputIterator’ (‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<char>*, std::vector<std::vector<char> > >’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<char>*, std::vector<std::vector<char> > >’)
      const size_t n = std::distance (it, itr);
                                             ^
```

I'm aware that I can fix this particular instance by calling `cbegin()` and `cend()` rather than `begin()` and `end()`, but since `begin()` and `end()` return a type that should be convertible to `const_iterator`, I'm not sure I understand why this is needed.

Why does `auto` deduce a type in this case that is not convertible to `const_iterator`?

Comment: Can't we reduce this code down to: https://gist.github.com/sharth/fbe0cddbe9a200d82b89

Comment: it is, but you dont cast it. there is no implicit casts done to try match overloading

Comment: @sp2danny:  I think that's my answer.

Comment: Before you typed the title of your question, did you not notice that the compiler was converting `auto it = foo.begin()` to `const_iterator` on the very next line and not complaining about it?

Comment: consider using `cbegin` and `cend` instead of `begin` and `end` when you don't need to modify.

Comment: @Yakk:  Of course I did.  That's kind of the whole point.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9622264/819272

Comment: Then, why did you claim it could not convert to `const_iterator` when converting it to `const_iterator` compiled?

Comment: @Yakk:  I probably could have worded & framed the question better.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to the following example, which fails for the same reasons.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it1 = v.begin();
    auto it2 = v.end();
    auto n = std::distance(it1, it2);
}
```

[`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) is defined using the same template parameter type for both arguments, and template argument deduction is failing because you have a `const_iterator` and `iterator`.

User defined conversions are not considered when deducing template arguments from function calls, and since the two arguments have different types in this case, and both are participating in template argument deduction, the deduction fails.

*§14.8.1/6 [temp.arg.explicit]*

> Implicit conversions (Clause 4) will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function parameter if the parameter type contains no *template-parameters* that participate in template argument deduction.

*§14.8.2.1/4 [temp.over]*

> `...` [ *Note:* as specified in 14.8.1, implicit conversions will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function parameter if the parameter contains no *template-parameters* that participate in template argument deduction. Such conversions are also allowed, in addition to the ones described in the preceding list. *—end note* ]

You'll need to convert the `iterator` to `const_iterator`, or specify the template argument to `std::distance` explicitly.

```
auto n = std::distance(it1, static_cast<decltype(it1)>(it2));
```

or

```
auto n = std::distance<decltype(it1)>(it1, it2);
```

Other options are, of course, to not use `auto` and explicitly specify the iterator type in both cases, or use the `vector::cbegin()` and `vector::cend()` member functions when you need to ensure that the type is a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I thought the deduction should have been automatic.  Doesn't a conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator` kind of defeat the point of using `auto` here in the first place?  +1 anyway.

Comment: @JohnDibling User defined conversions are not considered for template argument deduction, only a single standard conversion sequence can be applied, which is not the case here.

Comment: I think *that* is the real answer to my question.

Comment: @JohnDibling Type deduction is done before overload resolution, and does _not_ take into consideration most implicit conversions.  (There are a few, like array to pointer, which are considered.)  And overuse of `auto` is a good way to get such errors (or worse, code that doesn't do what you want).

Comment: @Praetorian Re your bottom two snippets: wouldn't the best solution here be to just drop the `auto`, and spell out the types he wants?  Or use `auto` for all of the iterators?  (And the `auto` for `n` is likely to cause surprises down the road.  Unlike `begin` and `end`, I'll bet that most programmers don't know what type `std::distance` returns.)

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Part of the reason why I'm going through this exercise is to come to some kind of consensus in my own mind as to when `auto` should and should not be used.  This is leading me to the conclusion that it should be used not liberally by judiciously.

Comment: If we are using c++11, you might as well use `std::vector::cbegin` and `std::vector::cend` rather than `decltype` :) I would consider the resulting code clearer. Also, since we are dealing with vector, the iterators could be dereferenced in order to return to simple pointer casts (ie using `&(*iterator)`), and use distance on these.

Comment: @John I lean more toward the *use auto eveyrwhere* camp, and reducing the verbosity of having to spell out iterator types is one of the prime use cases for `auto`, IMHO. You do run into a few gotchas like this one, but you learn to avoid them in no time. In particular, when using `auto`, I tend to use `cbegin()` and `cend()` in places where I know I only need `const_iterator`s.

Comment: @JohnDibling That's been my experience as well.  `auto` hides information about the type.  Information which is, often, vital to the understanding of the code.  It has it's place, but overuse is obfuscation.  And it opens the door to too many traps for the unwary (accidentally using an unsigned type for an arithmetic value, for example).

Comment: @Praetorian The systematic use of `cbegin()` and `cend()`, where appropriate, is certainly a step forward; stating explicitly what you want, rather than getting one thing or another depending on some distant context.  And while the use of `auto` is often obfuscating, spelling out iterator types in full isn't necessarily the clearest either; I use `auto` myself in for loops, or with a `while` when the iterator is declared just before the loop.  Those are about the limits, however.  Anything more is obfuscation.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing common with the iterator conversion. The compiler simply unable to determine the template argument. It is the same if you would write

```
int x = 10;
long y = 20;

std::cout << std::max( x, y ) << std::endl;
```

though an object of type `int` can be implicitly converted to an object of type `long`.

As for your example you could write

```
const size_t n = std::distance<std::vector<char>::const_iterator> (it, itr);
```

Comment: Actually I think I will be abandoning `auto` altogether here, as it doesn't seem to actually gain me anything.

Comment: @John Dibling If you deal with different types with one expression it is better at least for readability to specify their types explicitly instead of using auto.

Comment: Well, I have always agreed with that.  I was trying to be "scientific" here, and not allow my previous assumptions & expectations to cloud my judgement about the general applicability of `auto`, but it seems I still agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does auto deduce a typ[e in this case that is not convertible to const_iterator?

- You have two available overloads for `begin()` :

**Signatures:**

```
iterator begin();

const_iterator begin() const;
```

You declared your vector as `Packets test (100);`, which is non const.

If you declare it const, `auto` type deduction will have the second `begin()` overload as a best (and unique) match.

[It compiles and run with this simple fix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d3fdd3771c83e19).

Comment: OK, but while that might work here, it won't work in my real use case where `Packet` is not `const.`

Comment: @JohnDibling I see, in that case Praetorian answer will fit, I wanted to answer your last question.